# How can I view all the results outputted to the Command Prompt?

Tags: wireless-networking, prompt, aircrack-ng

The output from [running aircrack-ng](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/) shows all the packets from the capture file, but I'm unable to view the top of this output, only the last 150 lines.

I need to view the top in order to find the target network with the most IV's. How can I do this?

Comment: Windows command prompt?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your operating system you could use a redirect to save the output of your command to a text file then you can review it in your text editor of choice

> aircrack-ng > output.txt

Comment: This works on every OS that I'm aware of.  It works great because you can analyze the output later.  You can also add "2> error.txt" to redirect the "error" output to a separate files.  These are 2 separate streams, and sometimes contain different information.

Answer (score 2):

I usually pipe it to the `more` command:

```
aircrack-ng | more
```

It will work on pretty much all PC OSs.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the height and buffer of the screen.  Left click the top left corner of the Command prompt or hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd>

You can change the **current** instance by going to **properties**.  To make permanent changes, select **defaults**.